# Joomla Password Authentication in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, joomla, passwords, mysql-connector, password-encryption

I have managed to successfully connect remotely to the MySQL database for my **Joomla! 1.5** website using MySqlConnector in **Visual Basic .NET 2010**.

Now I am trying to authenticate a user's password from values submitted in a simple form to those retrieved from a MySQL query.

I found a useful thread on forums.joomla.org titled ["Joomla password MD5 & VB.NET MD5"](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2490030), but the code snippets there produce the incorrect hash.

Here is another useful Joomla Forums thread as to how [passwords are encrypted](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=431&t=195712) (using MD5 hash and "salt") in the Joomla DB.

Here is a modified version of the code:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

...

Private Function JoomlaUserAuth(ByVal Password As String, ByVal EncryptedPassword As String) As Boolean

    'HashedPassword:Salt = value from Joomla DB

    Dim Values() As String = Split(EncryptedPassword, ":")
    Dim HashedPassword As String = Values(0)
    Dim Salt As String = Values(1)


    Dim NewHashedPassword As String = GetHash(Password & Salt)

    Return NewHashedPassword.Equals(HashedPassword)

End Function


Private Function GetHash(ByVal StringToHash As String) As String
    Dim md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim encoder As New UTF7Encoding()
    Dim encStringBytes As [Byte]()

    encStringBytes = encoder.GetBytes(StringToHash)
    encStringBytes = md5.ComputeHash(encStringBytes)

    Dim strHex As String = String.Empty
    For Each B As Byte In encStringBytes
        strHex &= String.Format("{0:x2}", B)
    Next

    Return strHex

End Function
```

The result is that "NewHashedPassword" and "HashedPassword" are very different using the correct password/DB encrypted password combination. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. I was testing this code using an administrator's credentials, but after trying a standard user, it worked! Is there a different encryption method for Admins in Joomla?

Comment: Joomla passwords are salted by default, if you manually create a user without the salt it should still work. Did you manually create the other user?

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct hash for the user password you should input the password twice, something like:

Dim NewHashedPassword As String = GetHash(Password & Password & Salt)